# Mine data from QPublic

Tags: data

I am interested in extracting data from QPublic for every parcel in my city. I am a complete beginner with this and am not even sure which programming languages I should be looking into. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure that what you are trying to do is legal? It seems like they want to sell the data.

Comment: Actually, they charge the municipalities to host and deliver the data. I clicked through to one of the sites. There's no mention about not scraping data from the site, but it still feels...wrong.

Comment: OK, let me explain the reason that I am doing this. I'd like to make a heat map showing the accessed real estate value per square foot in my city. I can't make this map without having the data for each and every parcel. I see no difference between going to each page and getting this data manually vs. writing software to get it for me.

Comment: Yes, but the envisioned usage is the John Q. Public getting info about one or maybe a few parcels not hundreds. And, a scraper could overwhelm the server.

Comment: So I set the software to load one page every minute to not overwhelm their servers... I have nothing against QPublic and do not intend to cause them or their servers any harm. It's just that the analysis that I want to do is impossible from the interface that they've provided.

Comment: Chris Baze-- Ever figure this one out?